# Associating different LookAt with different placemarks in the kml file

Tags: google-maps, kml, google-earth-plugin

I have defined multiple placemarks in a kml file I have created, where I have associated a specific TimeSpan value with each placemark.

I now want to also change the LookAt settings for each placemark. Thus, as the time changes over min and max values of the specified TimeSpans for different placemarks, I want also to be able to vary LookAt settings.

However, as soon as I assign two different LookAt settings to two placemarks, Google Earth seems to ignore both these LookAt settings.

There is a related discussion in a prior post:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/kml-support-getting-started/cN_sqrvT-6Q

The problem I am facing is thus discussed in the above post. However, the solution suggested here is not applicable for me. I don't want to have one global LookAt setting that I would declare at the Document level. My need is to be able to define different LookAt settings for different Placemarks, where each Placemark has an associated TimeSpan.

Is there any way I can do this? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a sample of your KML?